# Sqlite SUM Entity value depending on LEFT JOIN value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm using Room on Android to query a POJO.

My POJO (Transaction) contains a `value` and an `account_id`. It further contains an `account` (instance of Account), which is fetched by a `@Relation`.

The transaction class:

```
@Parcelize
class Transaction(
    @Embedded val entity: TransactionEntity,
    @Relation(entity = Account::class, parentColumn = Database.Transactions.COL_ACCOUNT_ID, entityColumn = Database.Accounts.COL_ID) val account: Account? = null
) : Model
```

The accounts properties:

```
data class Account(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_ID) val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_NAME) val name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_BALANCE) val balance: Double = 0.0
)
```

The `accounts.balance` is not a value in the database, but the sum of all `transactions.value` belonging to that account.

So I need to sum every `transaction.value` where `transaction.account_id = account.id`.

It should work similar to this way, but I'm not getting it right:

```
@androidx.room.Transaction
@Query(
    """
        SELECT transactions.* FROM transactions
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT transactions.value, SUM(transactions.value) AS balance FROM accounts) ON transactions.account_id = accounts.id
        GROUP BY transactions.id
"""
)
fun getTrs(): List<Transaction>
```

Comment: What is the reason for `LEFT JOIN` (as opposed to `INNER JOIN`)?

Comment: assuming you want the balance for a known account why not simply `select sum(t.value) from transactions t where t.id = 'myknownaccounid'` ?

Comment: if you want something global. `select t.id, sum(t.value) from transactions group by t.id;`

Comment: i don't get the need of a joint.

Comment: @Tuckbros Sorry for the late answer, I want an Account object with the sum/balance of it's related transactions.
That's why I think a JOIN is needed.

Comment: I don't know anything about POJO so I can't help you with building an object. but if you want to retrieve balance of a given account (account id is know prior to building the object then this single balance value can be retrieved with the first query. If you want to collect more than balance at once, ie data from account table then you will need to get them, join or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it by creating a new POJO wrapping my original account object, but adding a field for the sum which is now queried.

```
@Query(
    """
        SELECT accounts.*, 
        (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.type = ${Transaction.TransactionType.EARNING} THEN transactions.value 
        ELSE -transactions.value END) FROM transactions WHERE transactions.account_id = accounts.id) AS balance
        FROM accounts
        LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.account_id = accounts.id
        GROUP BY accounts.id
    """
)
fun getAccountsWithBalance(): LiveData<List<AccountWithBalance>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
@androidx.room.Transaction
@Query(
    """
        SELECT transactions.* FROM transactions
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT transactions.value, SUM(transactions.value) AS balance FROM accounts GROUP BY transactions.id) ON transactions.account_id = accounts.id 
"""
)
fun getTrs(): List<Transaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have list all necessary columns of your table transactions in GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT transactions.* SUM(transactions.value) AS balance
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN accounts ON transactions.account_id = accounts.id
GROUP BY ...transactions.id, transactions.account_id.... and all necessary columns of transactions table...
```

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,(SELECT SUM(transactions.value) FROM accounts a ON t.account_id = a.id) AS balance
FROM transactions t
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it clean:
Create a balance view first

```
CREATE VIEW v_balance AS 
SELECT account_id, SUM(value) as account_balance
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY account_id
```

Then use the view in left join as desired:

```
SELECT account.*, IFNULL(v_balance.account_balance, 0.0) 
FROM account
LEFT JOIN v_balance ON v_balance.account_id = account.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably meant alike this:

```
SELECT a.*, SUM(t.value) AS balance
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN accounts a
ON a.account_id = t.account_id
GROUP BY t.account_id
```